# HOW to configure Xournal to delete by stroke by default

Tags: xournal

I have been using the software Xournal extensively in the last 15 years, under various operating systems, and lately as a virtual board in class (which I export to pdf for the student after class).

One very useful feature is the "delete strokes" mode of the eraser, which is not the default mode.  I would like this option to be selected by default (to save 3 seconds every time I start xournal).  I tried to save the option "as default" and to "save preferences" without success. Some other features DO seem to be saved and recovered from the preferences, but not this one. I tried to download the source code and to edit it, but got a bit lost in it.

Is there an easy way to configure Xournal to delete by stroke by default?

Answer (score 2):

With the help from my favorite system administrators, we found the following hack which totally solves my problem (albeit a more elegant solution is still welcome!):

- On Debian, the configuration file of Xournal (created after selecting
  "save preferences" at least once) is in  file:~/.xournal/config
- The option is in line 121"

  ```
  # default eraser mode (standard = 0, whiteout = 1, strokes = 2)
  ```
- Replacing 0 by 2 does the trick

  ```
  eraser_mode=2
  ```